# action returns empty string on ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, zend-framework2

I am trying to send a json object with an ajax post request.
something is wrong on what i am doing. here is my code.

```
    $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data : data,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
    });
```

the console.log in the error section is throwing an empty string no matter what i try to return in my action. here is a part of the code the ajax post is posting to:

```
    public function saveInfosAction(){
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $eav = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Frontend\Model\Eav');
        return "test";
    }
```

can somebody give me a hint why it is not working?
thanks in advance

Comment: where do you define the variables `data` and `formURL`?

Comment: Try `return new JsonModel(array('foo' => 'bar'));`; be sure to include the `JsonModel`

Comment: var formURL = form.attr("action");
for debugging issues im using data = {eav: 'eav', board:'board}

Comment: i think that your request is not even reaching the server .
whats the value of `jqXHR.readyState`,`jqXHR.status` and `jqXHR.responseText` in ajax error?

Comment: jqXHR.state -> function(), jqXHR.status ->0, jqXHR.responseText --> (an empty string)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all!
I found the problem.

I tried to trigger the submit by clicking on a link with

```
    jQuery("#submitInfo").on('click',function(e){..)
```

but i forgot this line

```
    e.preventDefault();
```

so the form wasn really posted with the ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

where you define url and data
try direct url like `url:http://example.com/myfile.php`
           data like

```
data:{'id':id, 'name': name}
```

also sending json then `dataType :'json'`

try

```
$.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data : data, // data will be like data : {data:data, id: id},
        dataType :'json',
        success:function(data) 
        {
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
});
```

also send back your response using `echo` or `print` not return

Comment: thanks. its still not working. formURL is "\saveinfos" maybe its something wrong with that? other form actions (non ajax posts) looks in the DOM the same (\savegame for saveGameAction). and they work.

Answer (score 0):

if `jqXHR.readyState=0` and `jqXHR.status=0` then in my experience it is a cross domain problem. notice that if your site is loaded with `http://www.domain.com` and your ajax is to `http://domain.com` or Vice versa, it would be considered a cross domain request.

open your page in chrome and open console (right click in page->inspect element->console tab)
run your ajax again and see what error you are getting .

chrome provides more detailed information about the ajax errors even when Firefox doesn't say anything

Comment: ok with the absolute domain at least the post is not longer aborting (ff said). but the jqXHR messages are still the same

Comment: did you tried it with chrome as i said "chrome console provides more detailed information about the ajax errors"

Comment: i tried and they are the same. in the network tab the status for the post is "canceled". the ajax request is not even reaching that action. i assume its just a little ugly thing i am overlooking

Comment: can u uploaded somewhere so i can test it ?

Comment: waht do you need source code? screenshot? i cant set up an testserver now.

Comment: if you cant setup a test server then just allow your local server to be accessed from internet and give me your ip and the url to access the page

Answer (score -1):

While using ajax, you have to return the value from the ajax request page using `echo`. Change `return` to `echo`.

```
echo "test";
exit;
```

Comment: This is just wrong :) It's a way, yes, but certainly not the preferred one.